# Inserting in a linking table does not work in Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload

I have Album entity and Image entity with OneToMany relation. I created a form with multiple image upload and, I managed to insert in the table "Album" and "Image" but not in the linking table 'album_image ", why please ?

This is my code in my controller :

```
            $album = new Album();
        $imagesUploaded = $album->getImagesUploaded();
        $imagesStored = [];
        foreach ($imagesUploaded as $image) {

            $fileName = md5(uniqid('img_album_', true));
            $fileExtension = $image->guessExtension();
            $nomImageComplet = $fileName . '.' . $fileExtension;

            $image->move(
                $this->getParameter('albums_images_directory'),
                $nomImageComplet
            );

            $tinified = fromFile($this->getParameter('albums_images_directory') . '/' . $nomImageComplet);
            $tinified->toFile($this->getParameter('albums_images_directory') . '/' . $nomImageComplet);

            $img = new Image();
            $img->setExtension($fileExtension);
            $img->setFile($fileName);

            $em->persist($img);

            $imagesStored[] = $img;
        }

        $album->setImages($imagesStored);

        $em->persist($album);
        $em->flush();
```

Album.php :

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Image", mappedBy="album")
 *
 */
private $images;

/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @var
 */
private $imagesUploaded;
```

Image.php :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Album", inversedBy="images")
 */
private $album;
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add to your constructor on 'One' side

> $this->images = new ArrayCollection();

Image entity:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Image", mappedBy="album")
 */
private $images;

/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @var
 */
private $imagesUploaded;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->images = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

For the 'Many' side add the annotation

> - @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)

Album entity:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Album", inversedBy="images")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $album;
```

For upload image from you Album form just add relation to your AlbumType:

```
        ->add('imagesUploaded', FileType::class, [
            'label'   => 'Upload images'
        ])
```

Comment: It works almost, I do not have any data inserted in album_id :/

Comment: Maybe you need to change some logic, check relations.

Comment: Your logic must be: after $imagesUploaded - the object need to save to $images. Look this example, in this case, used the event listener. (@ORM\PreFlush()) http://blog.theodo.fr/2015/07/manage-multiple-files-upload-in-symfony/